# Return & sort users depending on lookup results

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongoDb collections for `users` and a collections for `messages`. My goal is to return a result of users that

1. Have the `role` of `patient`
2. Have messages (filter out any users that don't have messages)
3. The result is sorted via the latest message (i.e the user with the latest message should be on top of the result)

I'm fairly new to aggregations but attempting to use one to solve this. The query I have so far returns users with messages via a lookup however does not filter out users without messages (2) nor does it sort the result (3).

```
db.users.aggregate([
    
    {$match: {role: "patient"}},
    {$lookup:
     {
       from: "messages",
       localField: "phoneNumber",
       foreignField: "phoneNumber",
       as: "messages"
     }
}

])
```

Comment: can you post the sample result after these above aggregation steps and expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can do that via the aggregation pipeline, a much more efficient solution is to write the most recent message's timestamp into the user at which point no join would be needed to retrieve the data you need.

Comment: Wow, that's actually a really good idea! I assume I'd then be able to fetch users that a time stamp that is not null and sort the result?

Comment: This worked well and I'm marking it as the answer even tho it does not show the aggregation. Thank you again for your input :)